# redbird - how do I add custom headers

Tags: redbird

I need to change `Host` request header property in my POST request. Is there a way to do so? 
I already tried to:

```
redbird({
    port: 8001
    xfwd: 'https://final-url.com',
    secure: false,
    ssl: {
        port: parseInt(port),
        key: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev-key.pem'),
        cert: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev-cert.pem')
    }
});
```

`xfwd: false` is showing my localhost and this one does not work (probably read as `true`). I'd like to add property

```
header: { Host: "https://final-url.com" }
```